# EDITTEXT add data to a table from a previously loaded from a stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#

I need add to a edittext data previously loaded from stored procedure. But only add the first row of the column of name "Respuestas" the id of "Preguntas" is id cod_pregunta. But I need that the other "respuestas" too add to next edittext this is the code.

```
 public void mostrarDatos(int posicion)
        {
            CotiBenev = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Usuario"].ToString();
            Batchid = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["iBatchId"].ToString();
            primerApellido = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Primer apellido"].ToString();
            segundoApellido = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Segundo apellido"].ToString();
            primerNombre = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Primer Nombre"].ToString();
            segundoNombre = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Segundo Nombre"].ToString();
            cons_pregunta = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["consecutivo pregunta"].ToString();
            cod_pregunta = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Codigo pregunta"].ToString();
            cod_aportante = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Codigo aportante"].ToString();
            Respuesta = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Respuesta"].ToString();
            rutaTapa = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Ruta Tapa"].ToString();
            rutaAnexo = tablaVerificacionAnexosV.Rows[posicion]["Ruta Anexo"].ToString();
        try
        {
            imagenTapa = new Bitmap(rutaTapa);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            botonSiguiente();
        }
        try
        {
            imagenAnexo = new Bitmap(rutaAnexo);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            botonSiguiente();
        }

        //  textBoxCantidadRegistrosV.Text = cantidadRegistros;
        //textBoxNumeroRegistroV.Text = (posicion + 1) + "";
        textBoxCotiBene.Text = CotiBenev;
        //   activarCamposValidacionAnexos();
        pictureBoxTapa.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBoxAnexo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBoxTapa.Image = (Image)imagenTapa;
        pictureBoxAnexo.Image = (Image)imagenAnexo;
        //      textBoxValorTapaV.Focus();

        textBoxCotiBene.Text = CotiBenev + ": " + primerApellido + segundoApellido + primerNombre + segundoNombre;

        string caseSwitch = cod_pregunta;
        switch (caseSwitch)
        {
            case "1.1":
                textBoxPreg_1_1.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.2":
                textBoxPreg_1_2.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.3":
                textBoxPreg_1_3.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.4":
                textBoxPreg_1_4.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.5":
                textBoxPreg_1_5.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.6":
                textBoxPreg_1_6.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.7":
                textBoxPreg_1_7.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "1.8":
                textBoxPreg_1_8.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.1":
                textBoxPreg_2_1.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.2":
                textBoxPreg_2_2.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.3":
                textBoxPreg_2_3.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.4":
                textBoxPreg_2_4.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.5":
                textBoxPreg_2_5.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.6":
                textBoxPreg_2_6.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.7":
                textBoxPreg_2_7.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.8":
                textBoxPreg_2_8.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.9":
                textBoxPreg_2_9.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.10":
                textBoxPreg_2_10.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.11":
                textBoxPreg_2_11.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.12":
                textBoxPreg_2_12.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.13":
                textBoxPreg_2_13.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.14":
                textBoxPreg_2_14.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.15":
                textBoxPreg_2_15.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.16":
                textBoxPreg_2_16.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.17":
                textBoxPreg_2_17.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.18":
                textBoxPreg_2_18.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.19":
                textBoxPreg_2_19.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "2.20":
                textBoxPreg_2_20.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "3.1":
                textBoxPreg_3_1.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "3.2":
                textBoxPreg_3_2.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "3.3":
                textBoxPreg_3_3.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "3.4":
                textBoxPreg_3_4.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "3.5":
                textBoxPreg_3_5.Text = Respuesta;
                break;
            case "4.1":
                textBoxPreg_4.Text = Respuesta;
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("No existe esa pregunta");
                break;
        }


    }
```

Comment: I don t know if its my average English, but I cant understand what you wanna do.